# Not able to export rdlc report to word, excel, or pdf in IE11?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have created Rdlc reports.So by default It provieds 3 options to export i.e. word, excel and pdf. I am able to export it in chrome, firefox but not in IE11.When I click on export to excel etc IE opens in new window and get closed immediately.Any help will be appreciated.....

Comment: What happens in IE11 ? no error ? nothing ?

Comment: can you add the code here..

Comment: IE opens in new window and closes immediately......

Comment: you could try to add the web page in compatibility mode. What is the version of report viewer ?